# YAML syntax error (Ansible) using playbooks

Tags: linux, centos, ansible, yaml

I use ansible-module-vcloud, and I want to create VMs via Ansible. For example, I want to create easiest playbook.

I have this code:

```
---

- name: vCloudDirectorAnsible
  hosts: localhost
  environment:
    env_user: admin
    env_password: admin
    env_host: vcloud.vmware.ru
    env_org: test
    env_api_version: 30.0
    env_verify_ssl_certs: false

- name: create catalog
  vcd_catalog:
        catalog_name: "test"
        catalog_description: "test_Descr"
        state: "present"
```

But I got error:

```
ERROR! 'vcd_catalog' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/root/ansible-module-vcloud-director/main.yml': line 14, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: create catalog
  ^ here
```

If I delete this part:

```
- name: create catalog
  vcd_catalog:
        catalog_name: "test"
        catalog_description: "test_Descr"
        state: "present"
```

My playbook will run and successfully completed.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the **tasks** keyword.

```
---

- name: vCloudDirectorAnsible
  hosts: localhost
  environment:
    env_user: admin
    env_password: admin
    env_host: vcloud.vmware.ru
    env_org: test
    env_api_version: 30.0
    env_verify_ssl_certs: false
  tasks:
    - name: create catalog
      vcd_catalog:
        catalog_name: "test"
        catalog_description: "test_Descr"
        state: "present"
```

Comment: Hi! Now, I get this err :

ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected '-' indicator

The error appears to have been in '/root/ansible-module-vcloud-director/main.yml': line 14, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


tasks:
^ here

Comment: @k0chan if that is supposed to come after the `env_verify_ssl_certs: false` that is of course not going to work, you cannot both have a sequence item and a mapping key at the root level of YAML file. Please provide a **complete** solution, that includes the first item of the OPs ansible file (and run it through a checker, to make sure it is at least valid YAML).